# How do I insert resizebox code in org-mode tables when exporting to latex?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export, org-table

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a resize command inside a table environment in org-mode that exports to latex,

Here is my minimal example of raw latex source vs org-mode tables:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{graphicx}


#+begin_src latex :exports results :results latex
\begin{table}
  \caption{a table that scales to the linewidth}
  \centering
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    A & 1\\
    B & 2\\
  \end{tabular}}
  \label{tab:scaled}
\end{table}
#+end_src
```

How can I make org-mode tables with a `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% }` command so that the same result is achieved for the table below? (Or alternatively something else that gives the same result).

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{graphicx}
#+CAPTION: a table that does not scale to the linewidth
#+LABEL: tab:uncaled
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
```

My attempt based on the [LaTeX-specific-attributes](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html) from org-mode manual

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{graphicx}
#+CAPTION: a table that does not scale to the linewidth
#+ATTR_LATEX: :math-prefix \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% :math-suffix }
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
```

However the things I've tried has not worked. In the answer provided to the question on [tex.stackechange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163246/resize-a-tabular-object-to-textwidth) another alternative is presented, which requires insertion of another environment between table and tabular.

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{graphicx}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{adjustbox}    
#+begin_src latex :exports results :results latex
\begin{table}
  \caption{a table that scales to the linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      A & 1\\
      B & 2\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{adjustbox}
  \label{tab:scaled}
\end{table}
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some investigation i figured out a solution.

Not sure why I didn't see it before or if table export changed in org-mode at some point.

org-mode export tables default as

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
A & 1\\
B & 2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

if the caption and/or label is not specified.
Now a table environment can be added around the tabular environment with a caption and label.

```
#+begin_table
#+LATEX: \caption{Description of table.}
#+LATEX: \label{tab:my-table}
#+LATEX: \adjustbox{max width=\linewidth}{
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center nil
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
#+LATEX: }
#+end_table
```

Notice the `attr_latex: :center nil`.
The adjustbox does not play well with `\begin{center}...\end{center}`.

The specific command I use here only shrinks the table, however any command can be inserted now.

Answer (score 2):

A late reply but may I suggest another solution ? Instead of resizing the table, you may want to split the lines when they exceed a given limit, for example `textwidth` :

```
#+caption: Your table
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment tabularx :width \textwidth :align XX
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
```

Pros : less code ! It also avoids very small, unreadable tables.

Cons : You have to specify the number of columns in the `:align` flag with "X"es, not with numbers. 4 columns mean ":align XXXX" and not ":align 4"

Comment: Note that this solution also needs `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tabularx}`

Answer (score 0):

please refer my script that's work

```
* ttt
**** tt
#+begin_table
#+latex: \resizebox{0.5\columnwidth}{!}{%
 |------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------|
 |                  | HiFive1        | Arduino 101        | Arduino Zero      | Arduino UNO      |
 |------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------|
 | Microcontroller  | Freedom E310   | Intel Curie Module | Atmel ATSAMD21518 | Atmel ATmega328p |
 | Open Source RTL? | Yes            | No                 | No                | No               |
 | CPU speed        | 320+ MHz       | 32 MHz             | 48 MHz            | 16 MHz           |
 | CPU ISA          | RISC-VRV32IMAC | X86                | ARMv6-M           | AVR              |
 | Bits             | 32 Bit         | 32 Bit             | 32Bit             | 8 Bit            |
 | CPU Core         | SiFiceE31      | Intel Quark SE     | ARM Cortex        | AVR              |
 | USB              | Micro          | Regular            | 2Micro            | Regular          |
 | Flash            | 16384 KB       | 196 KB             | 256 KB            | 32 KB            |
 | PWM              | 9              | 4                  | 10                | 6                |
 | SRAM             | 16 KB          | 24 KB              | 32 KB             | 2 KB             |
 | Digital IO       | 19             | 14                 | 14                | 14               |
 | IO Voltage       | 3.3 V and 5V   | 3.3V and 5V        | 3.3 V only        | 5V only          |
 | DMIP’s          | 1.61 MHz       | 1.3 MHz            | 0.93 MHz          | 0.30 MHz         |
 | DMIP’s          | 3.16 mW        | 0.35 mW            | –                 | 0.10 mW          |
 | Total Drystones  | 515.2          | 41.6               | 44.64             | 5                |
 |------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------|
#+latex: %
#+latex: }
#+end_table
```

Comment: Please elaborate. How does this answer the question? What "file" are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry for bad description,  I just want to share success codes.